# language parameter rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need some help with mod_rewrite doing multiple things to the url procedurally:

- If the url starts with en,es,pt-br, remove it and add ?lang=$1
- If the url does not next have 'web/' in it, add it.
- If the url is blank, go to 'web/en/'
- None of them should actually rewrite the url

This means:

```
 http://www.domain.com/en  >> http://www.domain.com/web/?lang=en
 http://www.domain.com/en/mobile  >> http://www.domain.com/mobile/?lang=en
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# This is to prevent the rules from looping, they only work as on-shot
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the url is blank, go to 'web/en/'
RewriteRule ^/?$ /web/?lang=en [L,QSA]

# If the url starts with en,es,pt-br, remove it and add ?lang=$1 ,has /web
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt-br)/web(/?.*)$ /web$2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA,R]

# If the url starts with en,es,pt-br, remove it and add ?lang=$1 ,has no /web
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt-br)/?$ /web/?lang=$1 [L,QSA,R]

# If the url starts with en,es,pt-br, remove it and add ?lang=$1 ,everything else
RewriteRule ^/?(en|es|pt-br)/(.+?)/?$ /$2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA,R]
```

Comment: John, this seems to almost work. I am noticing that when going to domain.com/es/foo it does not load domain.com/web/foo?lang=es as it should. All other rules seem to work.

Comment: @LouisW Yeah, the example that you gave was **`http://www.domain.com/en/mobile  >> http://www.domain.com/mobile/?lang=en`**, so the rule I have takes `http://domain.com/es/foo` and redirects it to `http://omain.com/foo?lang=es`, no `/web/foo`.

Comment: See step 2, "If the url does not next have 'web/' in it, add it." It would need to build the url as it goes because of the different criteria.

Comment: @LouisW Wouldn't `/en/mobile` get rewritten to `/web/mobile/?lang=en` then? If that's the case, in the last rule, add a `/web` in front of the `/$2/?lang=$1` target.