# modrewrite language parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, switch-statement

I'm looking to use the language switch in our website using mod rewrite. Instead of showing:

```
https://www.website.com/rest/of/my-site?lang=it
https://www.website.com/en/rest/of/my-site
```

The problems comes here.
A Our current mod rewrite configuration:

```
# General rewrites
RewriteRule -p([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?module=page&id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule (news|nieuws)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=news&url_raw=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?module=page&url_raw=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
#rewriteRule contact(/|)$ index.php?module=contact&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?module=page&url_raw=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

B Mod rewrite and the PHP snippet
When the mod rewrite is working the user should be able to switch from

- website.com/en/rest/of/my-site
- website.com/it/rest/of/my-site

Instead of

- website.com/en/rest/of/my-site?lang=it

I have tried several options ([language parameter rewrite with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875284/language-parameter-rewrite-with-mod-rewrite)) but I do not come far enough with it.

Comment: Is the request always pointing to website.com/en if it is not an other locale? This means, can we rely on the fact that the first folder is representing the locale?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Al /en, /it etc. are pointing to the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?(.*?)&?lang=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%1?%2%4 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```